# How to use timer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

**I have this code:**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim num As String
        Dim message As String
        Dim name As String
        message = txtMessage.Text
        Dim count As Integer = Me.TblContactsBindingSource.Count
        If i < TblContactsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 Then 'stay within bounds

        i = i + 1 ' for all rows except Row0

        TblContactsDataGridView.Rows(i - 1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White ' restore previous highlight
        TblContactsDataGridView.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque 'new highlight
        num = Me.TblContactsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        name = Me.TblContactsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen() Then
            SerialPort1.Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
            SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)

            SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & num & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
            SerialPort1.Write(message & Chr(26))
            MessageBox.Show("Message has been successfully sent to " & vbNewLine & name & " (" & num & ") ", "Message Sent", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


        End If

    Else            'next row is off the bottom so
        'i = 0       'reset index
        'TblSmsDataGridView.Rows(TblSmsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White 'restore bottom row
        'TblSmsDataGridView.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque 'highlight top row  

    End If
```

**In a command button I have this:**

```
Timer1.Interval = 2000
Timer1.Enabled = True 'no need to enable it and start it; one or t'other
```

What happen is, the message box appears over and over. How can i trigger message box to automatically close once it is finished? I commented the code in the "else" because the it repeats over and over.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a custom message box. Normal message box wont do the thing you wanted. It will pop up every 2 second. best choice is to make a new form and show it as a message box. :)

Comment: Can i ask a favor how can i create custom messagebox. Just a little bit so that i can understand.

Comment: @Joannou look at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box), it has an implentation of a custom messagebox with a timer to close if there is no response. Sounds like what you are wanting

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `timer1.enabled = false` in the timer1.tick handler.